# react rendering on server and running on client

Tags: reactjs, prerender

Is it possible to serve a react.js app already rendered from the server side that than runs as a client side app in order to accelerate the page rendering time ?

To be clear, the app must still behave as a SPA, I simply want the requested view to come "already built"

I'm sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is called  [Universal Javascript](https://medium.com/@mjackson/universal-javascript-4761051b7ae9#.qpkc372yc).

Here is one boilerplate app that implements that concept:
https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example

Also there is a way to do this with a headless browser such as [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).